# Can i apply for a tourist visa (USA) if my mom lives in USA as a refugee?

Tags: visas, usa

I have been thinking on getting a US tourist visa but I'm afraid if it would be a issue that my mom lives in US in refugee statues plus I did live in the US illegally when I was 3 years up until 10 years. I Have lived in Mexico (where I was born)  and recently made a trip to Toronto (Canada) and came back to Mexico, would that maybe make a difference?

PS: Now I have read that people in refugee  states can apply for family members to go to the states but I don't intend to stay, I really just want to visit for a few weeks and come back to Mexico, and that process is very long.

Comment: pd2: i currently work in IT in Mexico and this company is American and I am in my last semester as Electrical - Electronics Engineer  in Mexico national autonomous university  (UNAM)

Answer (score 3):

You can of course apply for a tourist visa - the question is if you will get one.

You would need to make a convincing argument to the processing visa officer that you will not overstay. This seems difficult with your background story, but not impossible.

For example, showing that you have enough money to support yourself, you have significant personal relationships at your home country (being married, having kids), you have a nice permanent job, you own real estate, etc. If you have three or more 'yes' to that, you stand a chance.

There is no guarantee, and a lawyer might be able to help you present it convincingly. Do not lie, give them all the facts - the good, the bad, and the ugly - and be convincing.